# Does nickel precipetate gold and copper?

Tags: reactivity, precipitation

I dissolved some CPU s and RAM s  in aqua regia the day after I found a green solution with black powder in the bottom. So what just happened is it nickel or tin from solder?

[image: 4] [image: 3]

[image: 2] [image: 1]

Comment: The chart implies sharp boundaries where in fact they are indistinct. Magnesium does react with water, but very slowly (and aluminum and zinc can react with bases as well as acids), and the metals below hydrogen ca still be reacted with some acids.

Answer (score 1):

CPU and RAM ard made of millions of transistors. Each transistor is made of silicon or germanium doped with neighbors in the periodic table, like gallium. arsenic, or plenty of other elements in traces like indium, antimony, etc. And these transistors are interconnected by golden copper wires. Capacitors and resistors are made of still different metals or semi-metals. Your solution must have a complex composition. It is worth being analyzed by standard techniques of qualitative, then quantitative analysis

Comment: As you said silicon, which doesn't dissolve in aqua regia and even so the amount of those doping elements are decimals percent.